# Microsoft Band 2 Data Logging

Tags: ios, microsoft-band

I am trying to use the Microsoft Band 2 with my Custom iOS App

Can Microsoft Band be configured to sample and store a sensor data and then stream the data to a smartphone at a later time?

For example - sample and store the Light Sensor Every second and then stream the data an hour later when connected to a iPhone.

Are there any specs on how much storage is available in the Microsoft Band.

Answer (score 0):

Data Logging for later retrieval is not supported on the Microsoft Band or Microsoft Band 2. If you would like this considered for a future release, you can add a feature suggestions at the User Voice page: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a link where it states that logging is not supported.  Can I write an App on the Band that stores the data and talks to my app.

Comment: You can not write an app that runs on the Band.